# how to append data returned from ajax call to a dynamically created div, among many divs of same class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I append data returned from ajax call to a dynamically created div, which is among many divs  of the same 'class name' ?

My HTML:

```
<div class="post_area">
    <?php
        $connObj = new Connection();
        $conn = $connObj->getConnection();

        $sql = ("select * from posts ");

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ( $result ) {
        echo "<br><br>";
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        for($i = 0; $i<$rowcount; $i++){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?> 
    <h3>
        <?php 
          echo $row['title']."<br>"; 
        ?> 
    </h3> 

    <?php
     echo $row['description']."<br>";
    ?>

    <div class="post_comments">
        <div class="comments_only_box" id="cb">
            //displaying comments dynamically
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" class="input_comment">
    <input type="button" value="comment" name="submit_comment" class="comm" data-id="<?php echo $present_id;  ?>">
</div>
<?php $present_id = $row['id']; ?>
```

---

My ajax call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".comm").on('click', function () {

            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var comment = "helloworld";//example

            $.ajax({
                url: 'comment.php',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    comment: comment,
                    id: id,
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    $('#cb').append(data);

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I append the data it's appended to all divs--but I want to append it only to the presently clicked div

Comment: "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you." Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there is no div clicked, you click on button?

Comment: Code formatting is also really useful for making it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Your code outputs multiple elements with the same `id` (`"cb"`). This is invalid, you can't have more than one element with the same `id`.

Comment: (edited it for grammar and code formatting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone clicks your `comment` button, the click handler receives a reference to that specific element as `this`. Since that button is inside the `div`, you can use `closest` to find the `div` that contains the button, then update that `div`. E.g.:

```
$(".comm").on("click", function() {
    var $div = $(this).closest("div.post_area");
    // Do something with `$div`...
});
```

**Live example:**

```js
$(".comm").on("click", function() {
  var $div = $(this).closest("div.post_area");
  var $input = $div.find("input[name=comment]");
  var comment = $input.val();
  $("<p>").text(comment).appendTo($div);
  $input.val("").focus();
});
```

```css
.post_area {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 6em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Type in any of the comment boxes and click the button following it:</p>
<div class="post_area">
  <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" class="input_comment">
  <input type="button" value="comment" name="submit_comment" class="comm" data-id="...">
</div>
<div class="post_area">
  <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" class="input_comment">
  <input type="button" value="comment" name="submit_comment" class="comm" data-id="...">
</div>
<div class="post_area">
  <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" class="input_comment">
  <input type="button" value="comment" name="submit_comment" class="comm" data-id="...">
</div>
<div class="post_area">
  <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" class="input_comment">
  <input type="button" value="comment" name="submit_comment" class="comm" data-id="...">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```